# Is the implements clause also inheritable?

Tags: java, inheritance

When a class implements an interface, do the subclasses inherit the implemented interfaces too? For example

```
class A implements Runnable
{
   public void run()
   {
     // do something
   }
}

class B extends A
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       new Thread(new B()).start(); //works
   }
}
```

does this mean the implements clause also gets inherited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class A IS-A Runnable, and class B IS-A A, so class B IS-A RUNNABLE. Yes, they do.

Comment: Put another way: The Is-A relation is transitive :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, B both extends A and implements Runnable.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. That exactly how it works.

Comment: So would it be totally redundant to write `class B extends A implements Runnable` ?

Comment: @dlamblin - yes, redundant. There are some classes in the Java SDK that have these redundent imports, but they're really unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. B is also Runnable due to B's parent (A) is Runnable.